# ios string replacement with * upto 4

Tags: swift

I want to display a number with all stars except last four digits like account number. I had tried it is displaying last four digits as ****.
Here is my code.

```
let letters = "987654321"
let start = letters.endIndex;
let end = letters.index(letters.endIndex, offsetBy: -4);
let value = "****"
let result = letters.replacingCharacters(in: end..<start, with: value)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution creates the asterisk string with `String(repeating:count:)` depending on the length

```
let letters = "987654321"
let end = letters.index(letters.endIndex, offsetBy: -4)
let value = String(repeating: "*", count: letters.count-4)
let result = letters.replacingCharacters(in: ..<end, with: value)
print(result)
```

If the length of the string could fall below 4 use the `limitedBy` parameter and check for `nil`:

```
if let end = letters.index(letters.endIndex, offsetBy: -4, limitedBy: letters.startIndex) { ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: You could also use `String(repeating:count:)` instead of `Array(repeating:count)` and avoid the conversion. Also you could use a partial range `letters.replacingCharacters(in: ..<end, with: value)`. Also also you could just `let result = String(repeating: "*", count: letters[..<end].count) + letters[end...]` :) Or even `let result = String(repeating: "*", count: letters.dropLast(4).count) + letters.suffix(4)` if the string isn't guaranteed to be at least 4 characters long.

Comment: @Hamish thanks, I wanted to suggest a solution close to the question but `String(repeating:count:)` and the partial range are indeed more elegant.

Comment: As a mutating method you can also do `letters.replaceSubrange(..<end, with: repeatElement("*", count: letters.count - 4))`, with does not create an additional string.

Comment: @vadian this would crash if the string has less than 4 characters